# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine due to an unrecognized option

Tags: android-studio, java

I'm truing to start Android Studio on Ubuntu and the following error occurred.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Unrecognized option: -Xm4g
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I think I have mistakenly edited a file. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Depending on how you're starting the JVM, it could be in your control panel or in some `.ini` file.

Comment: I found it. Thanks @Mena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [find your config file](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html) (probably `studio.vmoptions`) and change that to `-Xmx4g` (which stands for max heap size)

Comment: I checked. But there is no -Xm4g in both studio.vmoptions file and studio64.vmoption file

Comment: In that case, maybe you have `STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS` environment variable set?

Comment: If you can't find anything, just look through the output of `env` and grep `/` for `-Xm4g`

Comment: @omajid Thanks. I found it.

Answer (score 1):

Change -Xm4g to -Xmx4g

If you don't know where the -Xm4g is comming from, run:

```
 grep -Ril "-Xm4g" "<android studio folder>"
```

or

```
grep -Ril "-Xm" "<android studio folder>"
```